# Multi-level nested dictionary in python from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert this excel table into a dictionary in python:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chapter1 | subtopic1 | detail1 | description1 |
|  | subtopic2 | detail2 | description2 |
| chapter2 | subtopic1 | detail1 | description1 |
| chapter3 | subtopic1 | detail1 | description1 |
|  |  | detail2 | description2 |
| chapter4 | subtopic1 | detail1 | description1 |

I expect output like this:

```
dictionary = {
    chapter1 : {
        subtopic1 : {detail1 : description1},
        subtopic2 : {detail2 : description2}
    },
    chapter2 : {
        subtopic1 : {detail1 : description1}
    },
    chapter3 : {
        subtopic1 : {
            detail1 : description1,
            detail2 : description2
        },
    },
    chapter4 : {
        subtopic1 : {detail1 : description1}
    }
}
```

I'm using pandas to read excel. So far I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

datapath = "EMDrugs.xlsx"

data = pd.read_excel(datapath)
data = data.fillna(0)

chap = data.Chapter
topi = data.Topic
drug = data.Drug
dose = data.Dose

x = 0

chap = chap.to_dict()
topi = topi.to_dict()
drug = drug.to_dict()
dose = dose.to_dict()

def mergeDictionary(dict_1, dict_2, dict_3, dict_4):
   dict_5 = {**dict_1, **dict_2, **dict_3, **dict_4}
   for key, value in dict_5.items():
       if key in dict_1 and key in dict_2 and key in dict_3 and key in dict_4:
               dict_5[key] = {value , dict_1[key]}
   return dict_5

#dicti = dict(zip(chap, topi, drug, dose))

print(mergeDictionary(chap, topi, drug, dose))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("EMDrugs.xlsx")
df = df.fillna(method="ffill") #fill with previous value
dictionary = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    chapter = row["A"]
    subtopic = row["B"]
    detail = row["C"]
    description = row["D"]
    
    if chapter not in dictionary:
        dictionary[chapter] = {}
    
    if subtopic not in dictionary[chapter]:
        dictionary[chapter][subtopic] = {}
    
    dictionary[chapter][subtopic][detail] = description

dictionary

###output:
        {'chapter1': {'subtopic1': {'detail1': 'description1'},
          'subtopic2': {'detail2': 'description2'}},
         'chapter2': {'subtopic1': {'detail1': 'description1'}},
         'chapter3': {'subtopic1': {'detail1': 'description1',
           'detail2': 'description2'}},
         'chapter4': {'subtopic1': {'detail1': 'description1'}}}
```